# How to place scrollbar just beside plots in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have multiple radial charts and my implemention contains a scrollbar on the right side of the screen/window. I load the radial chart images which I created and saved previously.I would like to place the scrollbar just beside radial charts. I am quite new to Tkinter and used scrollbar.pack widget. Here is the implementation:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pandas as pd

# Create the main Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Radial Charts")
root.geometry("1200x600")

# Create a canvas for radial charts
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)

# Create a vertical scrollbar for radial charts canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)

# Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the radial charts
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

# Configure the canvas to use the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

# Create a canvas for the line plot
line_plot_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=600, background='white')

# Load and display the radial charts
checkbuttons = []  # List to store the checkbuttons
selected_checkbuttons = []  # List to store the selected checkbuttons
line_plot_image = None  # Global variable to store line plot image
line_plot_image_tk = None  # Global variable to store line plot image in Tkinter format

# Example DataFrame with unique IDs
data = {'unique ID': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a dropdown menu for unique IDs
id_var = tk.StringVar()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=id_var, values=df['unique ID'], state='readonly')
dropdown.pack(fill=tk.X)

# Function to handle dropdown selection
def dropdown_selected(event):
    selected_id = id_var.get()
    # Perform actions based on the selected ID
    print(selected_id)

dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", dropdown_selected)

# Function to generate line plot path
def generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit):
    line_plot_path = f"path/line_plot_visit_{start_visit}_and_{end_visit}.png"
    return line_plot_path

# Function to display the line plot
def display_line_plot():
    line_plot_canvas.delete("all")  # Clear the line plot canvas
    if line_plot_image:
        # Adjust the desired width and height values
        desired_width = 400
        desired_height = 600

        # Resize the line plot image
        resized_image = line_plot_image.resize((desired_width, desired_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Convert the resized image to Tkinter-compatible format
        global line_plot_image_tk
        line_plot_image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

        # Display the resized line plot image on the canvas
        line_plot_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=line_plot_image_tk)

# Function to handle checkbox selection
def checkbox_selected():
    global line_plot_image  # Declare line_plot_image as a global variable
    selected_checkbuttons.clear()
    for cb, var in checkbuttons:
        if var.get() == 1:
            selected_checkbuttons.append(cb)
    if len(selected_checkbuttons) >= 2:
        start_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[0]["text"].split("_")[1])
        end_visit = int(selected_checkbuttons[1]["text"].split("_")[1])
        line_plot_path = generate_line_plot_path(start_visit, end_visit)

        line_plot_image = Image.open(line_plot_path)
        line_plot_image = line_plot_image.resize((400, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed

        display_line_plot()

# Load and display the radial charts
for i in range(1, 10):
    image_path = f"path/visit_{i}.png"  # Replace with the actual image path

    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Adjust the size as needed
    image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # Create a label to display the image
    label = tk.Label(frame, image=image_tk)
    label.pack()

    # Keep a reference to the image to prevent it from being garbage collected
    label.image = image_tk

    # Create an IntVar for each Checkbutton
    check_var = tk.IntVar()

    # Create a Checkbutton and place it on the bottom-right part of the image
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(label, text=f"visit_{i}", variable=check_var, command=checkbox_selected)
    checkbutton.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor=tk.SE)

    checkbuttons.append((checkbutton, check_var))  # Add the checkbutton and its associated variable to the list

# Pack the widgets
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
line_plot_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

# Create a window for the canvas containing the radial charts
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

How should I change my code so that 1) scrollbar is  beside radial chart 2) scrollbar only scrolls radial charts?